# How to remove background signal from a multiplicative process?

Tags: detection-limit

Suppose I have a continuous variable representing the outcome of a multiplicative process. I measure it using an instrument, but even samples without the process yield numerical readings. I've been subtracting this background, but now I realize it might not make sense since my variable is best modelled multiplicatively.

Any references on this topic? Should I consider multiplicative background removal instead?